# Inserting records from one table to another, but on a 'dynamic' table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume that I have a table 'A' which holds the client's orders - so it is updated within every second - and I want to copy every record of it and put it in a new table 'B'.

How would you manage to do that knowing that every moment new records are added/updated and you cant just simply 'copy + paste' it (cause in that moment new records will be added/updated) ? Do you know any way to do that ?

Comment: use trigger after update or insert  . Please go through it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm

Comment: @ Karthick Rajan: how ?

Comment: in trigger you can get what action(update or insert) is happening and what are columns with which are used for above action. so depend upon that you can update or insert into the table B

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_INSERTItemDetails ON TABLEA
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO 
    tableB
    (
        colB1,
        colB2,
        colB3
    )
    SELECT 
        colA1, 
        colA2, 
        colA3
    FROM 
        INSERTED
END
```

and make sure that you are inserting a NOT NULL value to column Primary column of table.

Similarly you created for UPDATE and DELETE actions, so you don't need to copy separately because all actions which happen in TableA it will affect TableB also.